# How to differentiate mail for different group

Tags: lotus-notes

Sorry if I brought this up again. I'm using Notes 6.5 and I am belong to several groups. I wonder if I can setup Notes to show different icon for mails with different group recipient? How can I highlight the mail exclusive for me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It would help to know what version of Notes you are using.  In Notes <s>6 &</s> 7, it's not so much an icon as 'message marking' - just a filled in circle:

1. From within the mail database, select *Actions -> Tools -> Preferences*.
2. Under Mail, select the *Message Marking* tab.
3. Click the *Recipients* tab.
4. Select any or all of the icons you wish to use to flag email - not much choice here. You can also specify any alternate or group names under which mail might be sent to you, for which you want these preferences to apply:

[image: Notes 7 mail preferences screen]

In Notes 8:

1. Select *File -> Preferences*
2. In the Tree, select *Mail* - the mail preferences appears
3. Select the *Attention Indicators* tab

**Update:**
I was wrong: The message marking I referred to at the top of the post doesn't exist in Notes 6.5.  In Notes 6.5:

1. No icons - You can set colors only - affects the entire row
2. No support for Groups - individuals only.
3. No support for recipients - senders only.

Sorry about that.  I upgrading to at least Notes 7 an option for you?  Notes 6.5 is quite old.  There's a good upgrade argument to be made simply for security concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Dave.
I'm using Notes6.5 and I got "color" instead of "Message Marking" tab in my Preferences, any ideas?